# change value in one sql database when title exists in other db Android / SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Android Studio and Java. In my app I have 2 SQLitedb's; one with general info like titles, subtitles, images etc (spotsDb). The other one I use to store Favorites (favDB; with only titles). Because the Favorites have to stay when I update app and the general info, there are 2 databases.

But I want to set the value of the key "favorite" to "yes" in the general db when the title exists in the favorites db. How can I do that? Is there an sqlite command for this just like you can check arrays or maps with contains(...)?

Answer (score 0):

[ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) one database to the other, and then just look up the titles:

```
UPDATE main.MyTable
SET favorite = 1
WHERE title IN (SELECT title
                FROM favorites.OtherTable);
```